# Knockoutjs afterMove event not firing for nested observable array

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable

Why is the afterMove event not getting fired in this jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/vishalhonnatti/JMSt7/3
When debugged on chrome this is the error shown http://beenabled.com/cdn/ko_err.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing 'data:children()' to sortable.  Instead, pass the observable: 'data:children'.  By using the () form you are passing the underlying JavaScript array, not the observableArray.

Comment: But is it a good practice to add an observable / observableArray in the model like I have done?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you have done.  It is common in code I have written to initialize an observable / observableArray with no value and then to load it at a later point in time.  Often you will be interacting with a server via AJAX and using the returned JSON to map to your View Model.  Take a look at the mapping plugin to see how that may be able to help you: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html